# meaning of 'frame by'

Tags: meaning, idioms

> This paper has been **framed by** two seemingly recurring topics in IS research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's to say the paper is set *in the context* of those two topics.  They are the background or basis for the present work.

Here's the relevant definition:

> frame: a basic structure that underlies or
>   supports a system, concept, or text